# Linux: Typical amount time before kill after term?

Tags: linux, signal, timing

In linux for a typical reboot/restart what is the standard amount of time given for a process to shutdown once given the term signal before the system kills it?

Answer (score 2):

For the `upstart(7)` `init(8)` replacement, each task can specify its own timeout with the `timeout` keyword. If the task doesn't specify a timeout, then a default is used:

```
/**
 * JOB_DEFAULT_KILL_TIMEOUT:
 *
 * The default length of time to wait after sending a process the TERM
 * signal before sending the KILL signal if it hasn't terminated.
 **/
#define JOB_DEFAULT_KILL_TIMEOUT 5
```